# Magento Product Detail pages not showing up: Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on boolean in Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php

Tags: php, magento, product, fatal-error

I am having am issue with ONLY the product pages not showing up on my eCommerce website. The home page, product list pages, etc. all show up.

I'm getting this message when I click into any product details page:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 390

Line 390 is:

```
foreach ($updateXml->children() as $child) {
    if (strtolower($child->getName())=='update' && isset($child['handle'])) {
        $this->merge((string)$child['handle']);
        // Adding merged layout handle to the list of applied hanles
        $this->addHandle((string)$child['handle']);
```